# How can I delete duplicates in a Dart List? list.distinct()?

Tags: list, dart

How do I delete duplicates from a list without fooling around with a set? Is there something like list.distinct()? or list.unique()?

```
void main() {
  print("Hello, World!");

  List<String> list = ['abc',"abc",'def'];
  list.forEach((f) => print("this is list $f"));

  Set<String> set = new Set<String>.from(list);
  print("this is #0 ${list[0]}");
  set.forEach((f) => print("set: $f"));

  List<String> l2= new List<String>.from(set);
  l2.forEach((f) => print("This is new $f"));
}
```

```
Hello, World!
this is list abc
this is list abc
this is list def
this is #0 abc
set: abc
set: def
This is new abc
This is new def
```

---

**Set** seems to be way faster!! But it loses the order of the items :/

Answer (score -12, accepted):

I have a library called [Reactive-Dart](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart) that contains many composable operators for terminating and non-terminating sequences.  For your scenario it would look something like this:

```
final newList = [];
Observable
   .fromList(['abc', 'abc', 'def'])
   .distinct()
   .observe((next) => newList.add(next), () => print(newList));
```

Yielding:

```
[abc, def]
```

I should add that there are other libraries out there with similar features. Check around on GitHub and I'm sure you'll find something suitable.

Answer (score 482):

**Use `toSet` and then `toList`**

```
  var ids = [1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6];
  var distinctIds = ids.toSet().toList();
```

Result: [1, 4, 5, 6]

**Or with spread operators:**

```
var distinctIds = [...{...ids}];
```

Comment: Now this is the Dart way (short and powerful)! THank you.

Comment: this is beautiful code-efficiency wise. Is it performance efficient as well? I will use this in a long for loop to avoid adding same elements.

Comment: Just keep in mind tho from the original docs 'The order of the elements in the set is not guaranteed to be the same'

Comment: This does not work for strings list `2019 - 01`. And... from docs: `The set may contain fewer elements than the iterable, if the iterable contains an element more than once, or it contains one or more elements that are equal`.

Comment: What doesn't work?    var ids = ["abc", "def", "def"];
  var distinctIds = ids.toSet().toList(); seems to remove the duplicate "def"

Comment: @AleksTi it does work for strings too and regarding the second point: well this is the point of the whole operation.

Comment: Would this work if the elements in the set are objects? or are they considered different bcause evaluated by reference? Edit: tried, it does not work

Comment: @user3808307 For anyone that want to use this for `Object`. Check this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030613/how-to-delete-duplicates-in-a-dart-list-list-distinct/66137459#66137459

Comment: @MertcanDiken that is not true, currently when using `.toSet()` a `LinkedHashSet` is created, which keeps the order of insertion. This means that doing `ids.toSet().toList()` will keep the order.

Comment: This does not remove duplicate enums for me.
Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Comment: I assume `set()` relies on the equality operator, so this does not necessarily work for complex objects where you would expect two objects to be duplicates when they are considered to be distinct by dart.

Answer (score 189):

I didn't find any of the provided answers very helpful.
Here is what I generally do:

```dart
final ids = Set();
myList.retainWhere((x) => ids.add(x.id));
```

Of course you can use any attribute which uniquely identifies your objects. It doesn't have to be an `id` field.

Benefits over other approaches:

- Preserves the original order of the list
- Works for rich objects not just primitives/hashable types
- Doesn't have to copy the entire list to a set and back to a list

**Update 09/12/21**
You can also declare an extension method once for lists:

```
extension Unique<E, Id> on List<E> {
  List<E> unique([Id Function(E element)? id, bool inplace = true]) {
    final ids = Set();
    var list = inplace ? this : List<E>.from(this);
    list.retainWhere((x) => ids.add(id != null ? id(x) : x as Id));
    return list;
  }
}
```

This extension method does the same as my original answer. Usage:

```
// Use a lambda to map an object to its unique identifier.
myRichObjectList.unique((x) => x.id);
// Don't use a lambda for primitive/hashable types.
hashableValueList.unique();
```

Comment: That's only answer that works fine for List of Objects Thanks man

Comment: Works for me when I needed to remove Map in List which has a specific value.

Comment: Best solution, needs more upvotes. Thanks!! It's the most generic, normally we have lists with objects not simple strings or numbers.

Comment: This is the kind of solution I was looking for, thanks. However, I'm a bit puzzled: why use [`.remove()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Set/remove.html) instead of [`.add()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Set/add.html)? It seems it would avoid to iterate the list twice: `final ids = Set(); myList.retainWhere((x) => ids.add(x.id))`.

Comment: @Delgan yes, using `.add()` is even better. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Working for an object List

Answer (score 51):

`Set` works okay, but it doesn't preserve the order. Here's another way using `LinkedHashSet`:

```dart
import "dart:collection";

void main() {
  List<String> arr = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "d"];
  List<String> result = LinkedHashSet<String>.from(arr).toList();
  print(result); // => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
}
```

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-collection/LinkedHashSet/LinkedHashSet.from.html

Comment: `Set`s default implementation is a `LinkedHashSet`, so this changes nothing

Comment: Per the [docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-collection/LinkedHashSet-class.html), "The LinkedHashSet also keep track of the order that elements were inserted in, and iteration happens in first-to-last insertion order." If order preservation is important, it may make sense to use the specific type offering this guarantee, rather than rely on what happens to (today) be the default implementation. While I have not seen the docs explicitly guarantee that default `Set()` will always preserve order, it seems unlikely to change since that could potentially break quite a bit.

Answer (score 33):

Try the following:

```
List<String> duplicates = ["a", "c", "a"];

duplicates = duplicates.toSet().toList();
```

Check [this code on Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/4d3a724429bbd605f4682b7da253a16e).

Comment: this is pure solution with 3rd support

Comment: @TeeTracker: What do you mean by "3rd support"?

Comment: doesn't work if the elements of the array are objects!

Comment: @MohammadDesouky try the following example

`
class Person {
  String name;

  Person(this.name);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is Person && runtimeType == other.runtimeType && name == other.name;

  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode;
}

void main() {
  List<Person> duplicates = [Person("a"), Person("c"), Person("a")];

  List<Person> uniqueItems = duplicates.toSet().toList();

  print(uniqueItems); // Output: [Instance of 'Person', Instance of 'Person']
}
`

Answer (score 26):

**Remove duplicates from a list of objects:**

```
class Stock {
  String? documentID; //key
  Make? make;
  Model? model;
  String? year;

  Stock({
    this.documentID,
    this.make,
    this.model,
    this.year,
  });
}
```

**List of stock, from where we want to remove duplicate stocks**

```
List<Stock> stockList = [stock1, stock2, stock3];
```

**Remove duplicates**

```
final ids = stockList.map((e) => e.documentID).toSet();
stockList.retainWhere((x) => ids.remove(x.documentID));
```

Comment: This is a lovely solution

Comment: This is very nice appproach to remove duplicates from JSON array

Answer (score 25):

//This easy way works fine

```
List<String> myArray = [];
myArray = ['x', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'o', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'r', 'a'];

myArray = myArray.toSet().toList();

print(myArray);
```

// result => `myArray =['x','w','y','o','r', 'a']`

Comment: noted that the ordering may not preserved because `set` is not guarantee  to preserve ordering.

Comment: Do you have a reference for `Set()` not guaranteeing to preserve order?

Comment: Set as a known data structure does not preserve ordering. Most languages have their own custom implementation for ordered sets. Here is the one for flutter: https://pub.dev/packages/ordered_set

Answer (score 23):

If you want to keep ordering or are dealing with more complex objects than primitive types, store seen ids to the [Set](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-core/Set-class.html) and filter away those ones that are already in the set.

```
final list = ['a', 'a', 'b'];
final seen = Set<String>();
final unique = list.where((str) => seen.add(str)).toList();

print(unique); // => ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Very nice uniqueness maker if one deals with more complex lists. Thank you very much !

Comment: This is the only one that worked when having a list of objects and needing unique by id. Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't be 'forEach' better than 'where'? 'where' is used for filtering (and should return bool):

Comment: This is the simplest, cleanest looking to me. Also, from the documentation, where returns a new lazy iterable... : Iterable<String> where(bool Function(String) test)
Returns a new lazy Iterable with all elements that satisfy the predicate test.

Answer (score 15):

I am adding this to [atreeon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030613/how-can-i-delete-duplicates-in-a-dart-list-list-distinct/51446910#51446910). For anyone that want use this with `Object`:

```
class MyObject{
  int id;

  MyObject(this.id);


  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return other != null && other is MyObject && hashCode == other.hashCode;
  }


  @override
  int get hashCode => id;
}

main(){
   List<MyObject> list = [MyObject(1),MyObject(2),MyObject(1)];

   // The new list will be [MyObject(1),MyObject(2)]
   List<MyObject> newList = list.toSet().toList();
}
```

Comment: Beautiful!! I'd like to say the `Set` uses `hashCode` to uniquely identify the object, That's why it works, if we don't override the `hashCode` and `operator` to our custom object, then `toSet()` won't work here!

Answer (score 11):

Using Dart 2.3+, you can use the spread operators to do this:

```
final ids = [1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6];
final distinctIds = [...{...ids}];
```

Whether this is more or less readable than `ids.toSet().toList()` I'll let the reader decide :)

Answer (score 11):

For  distinct  list of `objects` you can use [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package.

Example:

```dart
// ignore: must_be_immutable
class User extends Equatable {
  int id;
  String name;

  User({this.id, this.name});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id];
}

List<User> items = [
  User(
    id: 1,
    name: "Omid",
  ),
  User(
    id: 2,
    name: "Raha",
  ),
  User(
    id: 1,
    name: "Omid",
  ),
  User(
    id: 2,
    name: "Raha",
  ),
];

print(items.toSet().toList());
```

Output:

```
[User(1), User(2)]
```

Answer (score 9):

Here it is, a working solution:

```
var sampleList = ['1', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4'];
//print('original: $sampleList');
sampleList = Set.of(sampleList).toList();
//print('processed: $sampleList');
```

Output:

```
original: [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
processed: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 7):

Using the [fast_immutable_collections](https://pub.dev/packages/fast_immutable_collections) package:

```
[1, 2, 3, 2].distinct();
```

Or

```
[1, 2, 3, 2].removeDuplicates().toList();
```

Note: While `distinct()` returns a new list, `removeDuplicates()` does it **lazily** by returning an `Iterable`. This means it is much more efficient when you are doing some extra processing. For example, suppose you have a list with a million items, and you want to remove duplicates and get the first five:

```
// This will process five items:
List<String> newList = list.removeDuplicates().take(5).toList();

// This will process a million items:
List<String> newList = list.distinct().sublist(0, 5);

// This will also process a million items:
List<String> newList = [...{...list}].sublist(0, 5);
```

Both methods also accept a `by` parameter. For example:

```
// Returns ["a", "yk", "xyz"]
["a", "yk", "xyz", "b", "xm"].removeDuplicates(by: (item) => item.length);
```

If you don't want to include a package into your project but needs the lazy code,  here it is a simplified `removeDuplicates()`:

```
Iterable<T> removeDuplicates<T>(Iterable<T> iterable) sync* {
  Set<T> items = {};
  for (T item in iterable) {
    if (!items.contains(item)) yield item;
    items.add(item);
  }
}
```

Note: I am one of the authors of the *fast_immutable_collections* package.

Answer (score 5):

```
void uniqifyList(List<Dynamic> list) {
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    Dynamic o = list[i];
    int index;
    // Remove duplicates
    do {
      index = list.indexOf(o, i+1);
      if (index != -1) {
        list.removeRange(index, 1);
      }
    } while (index != -1);
  }
}

void main() {
  List<String> list = ['abc', "abc", 'def'];
  print('$list');
  uniqifyList(list);
  print('$list');
}
```

Gives output:

```
[abc, abc, def]
[abc, def]
```

Answer (score 2):

Mind this extension

```
extension IterableExtension<T> on Iterable<T> {
  List<T> distinct<U>({required U Function(T t) by}) {
    final unique = <U, T>{};

    for (final item in this) {
      unique.putIfAbsent(by(item), () => item);
    }

    return unique.values.toList();
  }
}

class Item {
  Item(this.name, this.id);

  final String name;
  final int id;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Item{name: $name, id: $id}';
  }
}

void main() {
  final list = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7];
  print(list.distinct(by: (item) => item));
  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

  final items = [Item('foo', 1), Item('bar', 2), Item('foo', 3), Item('bar', 4), Item('foo', 4), Item('bar', 3)];
  print(items.distinct(by: (item) => item.name));
  // [Item{name: foo, id: 1}, Item{name: bar, id: 2}]

  print(items.distinct(by: (item) => item.id));
  // [Item{name: foo, id: 1}, Item{name: bar, id: 2}, Item{name: foo, id: 3}, Item{name: bar, id: 4}]
}
```

Comment: Would this omit higher indexes or lower ones? I want my newly added items be added to the final array and remove previous ones.

Comment: @Hayyaun with `putIfAbsent` higher indexes are skipped, you may use `update` instead and use `update` callback to overwrite values for existing keys and therefore always have items of the highest index as the map values.

Comment: @Hayyaun and even have a `latest` parameter that will allow to control the behavior, like `unique.update(by(item), (current) => latest ? item : current, ifAbsent: () => item)`

Comment: So why not just extend `Item` from `Equatable` class, and use `items.reversed.toSet().toList()`. That would be pretty close to this solution, am I right?

Comment: @Hayyaun yeah, this way will work, but the extension is more flexible, you may always control the condition for a iterable that will be used to exctrat unique items, while `toSet()` will always use `==`

Comment: Ok, after hours of debugging I found an issue. using `.toSet()` is unsafe if you have more compared keys than one. This answer saved my time once more. Thank you.

Comment: @Hayyaun No problem, I'm glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

As for me, one of the best practices is sort the array, and then deduplicate it. The idea is stolen from low-level languages. So, first make the sort by your own, and then deduplicate equal values that are going after each other.

```
// Easy example
void dedup<T>(List<T> list, {removeLast: true}) {
  int shift = removeLast ? 1 : 0;
  T compareItem;
  for (int i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (compareItem == (compareItem = list[i])) {
      list.removeAt(i + shift);
    }
  }
}

// Harder example
void dedupBy<T, I>(List<T> list, I Function(T) compare, {removeLast: true}) {
  int shift = removeLast ? 1 : 0;
  I compareItem;
  for (int i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (compareItem == (compareItem = compare(list[i]))) {
      list.removeAt(i + shift);
    }
  }
}


void main() {
  List<List<int>> list = [[1], [1], [2, 1], [2, 2]];
  print('$list');
  dedupBy(list, (innerList) => innerList[0]);
  print('$list');

  print('\n removeLast: false');

  List<List<int>> list2 = [[1], [1], [2, 1], [2, 2]];
  print('$list2');
  dedupBy(list2, (innerList) => innerList[0], removeLast: false);
  print('$list2');
}
```

Output:

```
[[1], [1], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[1], [2, 1]]

removeLast: false
[[1], [1], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[1], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way...

```
final reducedList = [];

list.reduce((value, element) {
    if (value != element) 
        reducedList.add(value);
    return element;
});

reducedList.add(list.last);

print(reducedList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following way:

```
void main(List <String> args){
    List<int> nums = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5];
    List<int> nums2 = nums.toSet().toList();
}
```

NOTE: This will not work if the items in the list are objects of class and have the same attributes. So, to solve this, you can use the following way:

```
void main() {
  List<Medicine> objets = [Medicine("Paracetamol"),Medicine("Paracetamol"), Medicine("Benylin")];
  
  List <String> atributs = [];
  objets.forEach((element){
    atributs.add(element.name);
  });
  
  List<String> noDuplicates = atributs.toSet().toList();
  print(noDuplicates);
}

class Medicine{
  final String name;
  Medicine(this.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove duplicate data from any type of `map` or `list`.

```
 var list = [
     {"id": 1, "name": "piyush"},
     {"id": 2, "name": "jay"},
     {"id": 3, "name": "premal"},
     {"id": 4, "name": "piyush"},
     {"id": 5, "name": "nishant"}
    ];
    
    final ids = Set();
    randomProgramsList.retainWhere((x) => ids.add(x["name"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
var list = [
 {"id": 1, "name": "Joshua"},
 {"id": 2, "name": "Joshua"},
 {"id": 3, "name": "Shinta"},
 {"id": 4, "name": "Shinta"},
 {"id": 5, "name": "Zaidan"}
];
list.removeWhere((element) => element.name == element.name.codeUnitAt(1));
list.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));
```

Output:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Joshua"}, 
{"id": 3, "name": "Shinta"}, 
{"id": 5, "name": "Zaidan"}]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Model> bigList = [];
List<ModelNew> newList = [];  

for (var element in bigList) {
      var list = newList.where((i) => i.type == element.type).toList();
      if(list.isEmpty){
       newList.add(element);
      }
    }
```

Comment: There are **17 existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with over **three hundred votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

**Create method to remove duplicates from Array and return Array of unique elements.**

```
class Utilities {
  static List<String> uniqueArray(List<String> arr) {
    List<String> newArr = [];
    for (var obj in arr) {
      if (newArr.contains(obj)) {
        continue;
      }
      newArr.add(obj);
    }
    return newArr;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution

```
    List<T> removeDuplicates<T>(List<T> list, IsEqual isEqual) {
      List<T> output = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        bool found = false;
        for(var j = 0; j < output.length; j++) {
          if (isEqual(list[i], output[j])) {
            found = true;
          }
        }
        if (found) {
          output.add(list[i]);
        }
      }

      return output;
    }
```

Use it like this:

```
  var theList = removeDuplicates(myOriginalList, (item1, item2) => item1.documentID == item2.documentID);
```

or...

```
  var theList = removeDuplicates(myOriginalList, (item1, item2) => item1.equals(item2));
```

or...