# remove duplicate data from large data api in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, duplicates

i want to remove duplicate data from the array that i am getting from api and i have tried sorting, compairing, toSet().toList() but nothing seems to work.
below is the data that i am getitng -:

```
{
  "data":[
       {
      "laboratoryComponentId": 16,
      "laboratoryTypeId": 18,
      "laboratoryTypeName": "Profile1",
      "componentName": "LP-PLA2 Enzyme",
      "uom": "U/L",
      "componentDataType": "Numeric",
      "componentDataTypeValue": null,
      "laboratoryTypeSequence": 1,
      "laboratoryComponentSequence": 16
    },
    {
      "laboratoryComponentId": 17,
      "laboratoryTypeId": 18,
      "laboratoryTypeName": "Profile1",
      "componentName": "CRP C Reactive Protein",
      "uom": "mg/dl",
      "componentDataType": "Numeric",
      "componentDataTypeValue": null,
      "laboratoryTypeSequence": 1,
      "laboratoryComponentSequence": 17
    },
    {
      "laboratoryComponentId": 18,
      "laboratoryTypeId": 25,
      "laboratoryTypeName": "Profile2",
      "componentName": "Anti TPO (Anti Micro Somal) Antibody",
      "uom": "IU/ML",
      "componentDataType": "Numeric",
      "componentDataTypeValue": null,
      "laboratoryTypeSequence": 2,
      "laboratoryComponentSequence": 18
    },
    {
      "laboratoryComponentId": 19,
      "laboratoryTypeId": 25,
      "laboratoryTypeName": "Profile2",
      "componentName": "FT3",
      "uom": "pg/ml",
      "componentDataType": "Numeric",
      "componentDataTypeValue": null,
      "laboratoryTypeSequence": 2,
      "laboratoryComponentSequence": 19
    },
    {
      "laboratoryComponentId": 30,
      "laboratoryTypeId": 8,
      "laboratoryTypeName": "Profile3",
      "componentName": "Fg3",
      "uom": "pg/ml",
      "componentDataType": "Numeric",
      "componentDataTypeValue": null,
      "laboratoryTypeSequence": 3,
      "laboratoryComponentSequence": 30
    },
  
   ]
}
```

here i want to make 2 list one for "laboratoryTypeName" and other for "componentName" .
can anyone help how i remove duplicate data us add it to a object so that i can used all data when needed.
thanks

EDIT -:
below is the model class-

```
import 'dart:convert';

GetLaboratorComponents getLaboratorComponentsFromJson(String str) => GetLaboratorComponents.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String getLaboratorComponentsToJson(GetLaboratorComponents data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class GetLaboratorComponents {
  GetLaboratorComponents({
    this.data,
    this.exceptionInfo,
    this.message,
    this.messages,
    this.isSuccess,
  });

  List<LaboratorComponents> data;
  dynamic exceptionInfo;
  dynamic message;
  dynamic messages;
  bool isSuccess;

  factory GetLaboratorComponents.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetLaboratorComponents(
    data: List<LaboratorComponents>.from(json["data"].map((x) => LaboratorComponents.fromJson(x))),
    exceptionInfo: json["exceptionInfo"],
    message: json["message"],
    messages: json["messages"],
    isSuccess: json["isSuccess"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "exceptionInfo": exceptionInfo,
    "message": message,
    "messages": messages,
    "isSuccess": isSuccess,
  };
}

class LaboratorComponents {
  LaboratorComponents({
    this.laboratoryComponentId,
    this.laboratoryTypeId,
    this.laboratoryTypeName,
    this.componentName,
    this.uom,
    this.componentDataType,
    this.componentDataTypeValue,
    this.laboratoryTypeSequence,
    this.laboratoryComponentSequence,
  });

  int laboratoryComponentId;
  int laboratoryTypeId;
  String laboratoryTypeName;
  String componentName;
  String uom;
  dynamic componentDataType;
  String componentDataTypeValue;
  int laboratoryTypeSequence;
  int laboratoryComponentSequence;

  factory LaboratorComponents.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LaboratorComponents(
    laboratoryComponentId: json["laboratoryComponentId"],
    laboratoryTypeId: json["laboratoryTypeId"],
    laboratoryTypeName: json["laboratoryTypeName"],
    componentName: json["componentName"],
    uom: json["uom"] == null ? null : json["uom"],
    componentDataType: json["componentDataType"],
    componentDataTypeValue: json["componentDataTypeValue"] == null ? null : json["componentDataTypeValue"],
    laboratoryTypeSequence: json["laboratoryTypeSequence"],
    laboratoryComponentSequence: json["laboratoryComponentSequence"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "laboratoryComponentId": laboratoryComponentId,
    "laboratoryTypeId": laboratoryTypeId,
    "laboratoryTypeName": laboratoryTypeName,
    "componentName": componentName,
    "uom": uom == null ? null : uom,
    "componentDataType": componentDataType,
    "componentDataTypeValue": componentDataTypeValue == null ? null : componentDataTypeValue,
    "laboratoryTypeSequence": laboratoryTypeSequence,
    "laboratoryComponentSequence": laboratoryComponentSequence,
  };
}
```

Comment: duplicates = {list name}.toSet().toList();

Comment: tried but not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665923/how-to-remove-duplicate-elements-in-a-list-while-preserving-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `removeWhere` to find duplicate elements and remove it. I used two keys (typeName and Id).

```
GetLaboratorComponents labModel;

List<LaboratorComponents> dataList = [];

labModel = GetLaboratorComponents.fromJson(response);

labModel.data.forEach((element) {
  dataList.removeWhere((e) => element.laboratoryTypeName == e.laboratoryTypeName || element.laboratoryComponentId == e.laboratoryComponentId);
  dataList.add(element);
});

labModel.data = dataList;

return labModel;
```