# How to delete duplicate constructed objects in a list while preserving order and returning a List in dart?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a list of constructed objects called RecentCard which is basically an object with user id, pic, and name. I have created a list arranged in order of most recent interaction based on timestamp. However i need to get rid of the second occurence and onwards of any duplicated object. I am comparing just the ids since users may have the same name or photo, and i cannot remove duplicates from a simple list of uids because then i could lose the order of corresponding photos and names.

For example the list would look something like this :

```
List<RecentCard> recentCards= [RecentCard(uid:as721dn18j2,name:mike,photourl:https://sadadasd1d1),RecentCard(.....]
```

**I have searched for solutions but all of them are dealing with like primitive types like simple lists of strings and the solutions didn't work for me. For example this post: [How to delete duplicates in a dart List? list.distinct()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030613/how-to-delete-duplicates-in-a-dart-list-list-distinct)   Read below**

The first answer's link is no longer available, the next answer with sets is something i tried but it simply doesnt work i have no idea why maybe because its not a primitive type. The next answer with the queries package didn't work because i was using the list to build a listview.builder and so when i called list.length it said i couldnt call that on an iterable or something. The final solution wouldn't work because it said String is not a subtype of RecentCard.

I tried using two forloops with  the second just comparing first value to the next couple but that doesnt work because if a duplicate is found, the object is removed and the length is messed up so some elements get skipped.

Any ideas? I feel like its very simple but im not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [Set](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-core/Set-class.html) to store seen cards and then filter away those ones that are already in the set.

```
final seenCards = Set<String>();
final uniqueCards = recentCards.where((card) => seenCards.add(card.uid)).toList();
```

Comment: An example for anyone who wants to try it out https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a3a4160140584285b31189654aa59ab2

Comment: Thanks @Niko, this answer saved many efforts for me !!