# Having issue while removing duplicate items from a list in dart

Tags: list, dart

I want to remove duplicate items but didnt found any method

```
List items = data
            .where((test) =>
                test["title"].toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                test["ingredients"].toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                test["keywords"].toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
                test["author"].toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())).toSet()
            .toList();
```

here is the **output** with **duplication**

> [{ingredients:plus extra for rolling out (we like Wrights), keywords: Bread, author: Good Food, title: Spicy pizza, recipe_ID: 28},
>   {ingredients: plus extra for rolling out (we like Wrights), keywords: Indian, author: Good Food, title: Spicy pizza, recipe_ID: 28}, 
>   {ingredients:plus extra for rolling out (we like Wrights), keywords: Midweek, author: Good Food, title: Spicy pizza, recipe_ID: 28}]

so i want to remove these duplicate items,is there any method like **distinct?**

Comment: @pskink i tried but same issue.

Comment: What type of object are the results? Have you implemented `==` and `hashcode`?

Comment: yes i have tried to use this in my scenario but got no luck. Actually i am dealing with a lot of JSONs and HTTP requests so its very difficult to remove duplicate data from all of them.

Comment: Please let me know if there is any library Like "dartx" or any extension like distinct() is available for this purpose i'll be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030613/how-to-delete-duplicates-in-a-dart-list-list-distinct).
For your case:

```
var items = [
  test["title"],
  test["ingredients"],
  test["keywords"],
  test["author"]
]

var distinctItems = items.toSet().toList();
```

**NOTE:**
Above I have created the list statically for simplicity. You should created it dynamically. If you dont want to distinguish between small and capital letters, that also you will have to take care.

Comment: no, not the same code because i have different scenario i tried it with changings