# Dart - find duplicate values on a List

Tags: list, flutter, dart

how can I find duplicate values on a list,
Let's say I got a List like this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> users = [
    { "name": 'John', 'age': 18 },
    { "name": 'Jane', 'age': 21 },
    { "name": 'Mary', 'age': 23 },
    { "name": 'Mary', 'age': 27 },
  ];
```

How I can iterate the list to know if there are users with the same name?

Comment: You can get your answer from this question(It shows how to delete duplicate elements from a list) -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030613/how-to-delete-duplicates-in-a-dart-list-list-distinct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete duplicates in a dart List? list.distinct()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030613/how-to-delete-duplicates-in-a-dart-list-list-distinct)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple way would be this:

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> users = [
    { "name": 'John', 'age': 18 },
    { "name": 'Jane', 'age': 21 },
    { "name": 'Mary', 'age': 23 },
    { "name": 'Mary', 'age': 27 },
  ];
  List names = []; // List();
  users.forEach((u){
    if (names.contains(u["name"])) print("duplicate ${u["name"]}");
    else names.add(u["name"]);
  });
}
```

Result:

```
duplicate Mary
```

Comment: Change :  List names = List(); ===> List names = [];

Answer (score 4):

Here is my more concise and dependency free version to get all the duplicates or check for duplicates. The key is the toSet function that removes all the duplicates (we then compare the set and the list to identify if we have any)

```
extension List_E on List {
  bool hasDuplicates() => this.length != this.toSet().length;

  List getDuplicates() => this.where((x) => !this.toSet().remove(x)).toList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably a cleaner solution with extensions.

By declaring:

```
extension ListExtensions<E> on List<E> {
  List<E> removeAll(Iterable<E> allToRemove) {
    if (allToRemove == null) {
      return this;
    } else {
      allToRemove.forEach((element) {
        this.remove(element);
      });
      return this;
    }
  }

  List<E> getDupes() {
    List<E> dupes = List.from(this);
    dupes.removeAll(this.toSet().toList());
    return dupes;
  }
}
```

then you can find your duplicates by calling `List.getDupes()`

Note that the function `removeAll` doesn't exist in my current Dart library, in case you're reading this when they implement it somehow.

Also keep in mind the `equals()` function. In a `List<String>`, `["Rafa", "rafa"]` doesn't contain duplicates.

If you indeed want to achieve this level of refinement, you'd have to apply a `distinctBy` function:

```
extension ListExtensions<E> on List<E> {
  List<E> removeAll(Iterable<E> allToRemove) {
    if (allToRemove == null) {
      return this;
    } else {
      allToRemove.forEach((element) {
        this.remove(element);
      });
      return this;
    }
  }

  List<E> distinctBy(predicate(E selector)) {
    HashSet set = HashSet();
    List<E> list = [];
    toList().forEach((e) {
      dynamic key = predicate(e);
      if (set.add(key)) {
        list.add(e);
      }
    });

    return list;
  }

  List<E> getDupes({E Function(E) distinctBy}) {
    List<E> dupes = List.from(this);
    if (distinctBy == null) {
      dupes.removeAll(this.toSet().toList());
    } else {
      dupes.removeAll(this.distinctBy(distinctBy).toSet().toList());
    }

    return dupes;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a feeling Rafael's answer had code similar to Kotlin so I dug around and saw that these functions are part of the `kt_dart` library which basically gets the Kotlin standard library and ports it to Dart.

I come from a Kotlin background so I use this package often. If you use it, you can simply make the extension this much shorter:

```dart
extension KtListExtensions<T> on KtList<T> {
  KtList<T> get duplicates => toMutableList()..removeAll(toSet().toList());
}
```

just make sure to add `kt_dart` on your pubspec: `kt_dart: ^0.8.0`

**Example**

```dart
final list = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'apples'].toImmutableList();
final duplicates = list.duplicates; // should be ['apples'] in the form of an ImmutableList<String>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {

  List<String> country = [
    "Nepal", 
    "Nepal", 
    "USA",
    "Canada",
    "Canada",
    "China",
    "Russia",
];
List DupCountry = [];
country.forEach((dup){
if(DupCountry.contains(dup)){
print("Duplicate in List= ${dup}");
}
else{
  DupCountry.add(dup);
}
});

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [`groupBy`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/groupBy.html) from `package:collection`

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

List<Map<String, dynamic>> users = [
  { "name": 'John', 'age': 18 },
  { "name": 'Jane', 'age': 21 },
  { "name": 'Mary', 'age': 23 },
  { "name": 'Mary', 'age': 27 },
];

final duplicates = groupBy(
  // Group the list of users by 'name'
  // This creates a Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>>
  // Such that we have a map from name to list of users.
  users,
  (user) => user['name'],
)
  // Take values of the map from name to list of users.
  // This will be a list of lists of users.
  .values
  // Take each list that has more than once user with the same name
  .where((list) => list.length > 1)
  // Take the name of the first user for each list
  .map((list) => list.first['name'])
  // Make this to a list
  .toList();

print(duplicates); // [ Mary, ]
```

If you just want the names as in the example above, an easier way would be do:

```dart
final duplicates = groupBy(
  // Make an iterable of just the names, then group it by the
  // identity function. That means groupby name.
  users.map((u) => u['name']),
  (name) => name,
)
  // Take values of the map from name to list of names that are the same.
  // This will be: [['John'], ['Jane'], ['Mary', 'Mary']]
  .values
  // Take each list that has more than one entry
  // This will be [['Mary', 'Mary']]
  .where((list) => list.length > 1)
  // Expand these lists into a single list
  // This will be ['Mary', 'Mary']
  .expand((list) => list)
  // Make this as set to remove duplicate entries
  // {'Mary'}
  .toSet()
  // Make the set into a list (not really necessary)
  // ['Mary']
  .toList();

print(duplicates); // [ Mary, ]
```

Credit: https://github.com/dart-lang/collection/issues/324#issuecomment-1847446297

I wrote it up here because I thought such an elegant solution ought to be documented somewhere :D

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [`Iterable.fold`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html) from `dart:core` library

```dart
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> users = [
    {"name": 'John', 'age': 18},
    {"name": 'Jane', 'age': 21},
    {"name": 'Mary', 'age': 23},
    {"name": 'Mary', 'age': 27},
  ];

  // Make an iterable of just the names
  var userNames = users.map((u) => u['name']);

  // then fold
  var duplicateNames = userNames.fold((
    dups: <String>{},
    seen: <String>{},
    // (1) add item to the set 'seen'
    // (2) add item to the set 'dups' iff step (1) yeilds false(that is, item was already in the set 'seen')
  ), (prev, item) => prev.seen.add(item) ? prev : (dups: prev.dups..add(item), seen: prev.seen)).dups;

  print(duplicateNames); // {Mary}
}
```

##### Full version

```dart
extension ExtendedIterable<T> on Iterable<T> {
  /// Returns a new [Iterable] containing duplicate elements.
  ///
  /// If [key] is provided, elements are considered duplicate based on the result
  /// of applying [key] to each element. If [key] is omitted, elements are
  /// considered duplicate based on their own values.
  ///
  /// Note that [Iterable] returned from this method can contain duplicate entries.
  ///
  Iterable<T> whereDuplicate<K>({K Function(T)? key}) => _whereDuplicate(key ?? (i) => i);
  Iterable<T> _whereDuplicate<K>(K Function(T) key) => fold((
        dups: <T>[],
        seen: <K>{},
        // (1) add item to the set 'seen'
        // (2) add item to the set 'dups' iff item is already seen
      ), (prev, item) => prev.seen.add(key(item)) ? prev : (dups: prev.dups..add(item), seen: prev.seen)).dups;

  /// Returns a new [Iterable] containing distinct elements.
  ///
  Iterable<T> whereDistinct<K>({K Function(T)? key}) => _whereDistinct(key ?? (i) => i);
  Iterable<T> _whereDistinct<K>(K Function(T) key) => fold((
        distincts: <T>[],
        seen: <K>{},
        // (1) add item to the set 'seen'
        // (2) add item to the set 'distincts' iff item is not already seen
      ), (prev, item) => prev.seen.add(key(item)) ? (distincts: prev.distincts..add(item), seen: prev.seen) : prev).distincts;

  /// Returns a new [Iterable] containing unique elements(singlicates).
  ///
  Iterable<T> whereUnique<K>({K Function(T)? key}) => _whereUnique(key ?? (i) => i);
  Iterable<T> _whereUnique<K>(K Function(T) key) => fold((
        unqs: <T>[],
        seen: <K>{},
        dups: {..._whereDuplicate(key).map(key)},
        // (1) add item to the set 'seen'
        // (2) add item to the set 'unqs' iff item is neither seen nor duplicate
      ), (p, i) => p.seen.add(key(i)) && !p.dups.contains(key(i)) ? (unqs: p.unqs..add(i), seen: p.seen, dups: p.dups) : p).unqs;
}
```

Usage:

```dart
users.whereDuplicate(key: (user) => user['name']); // entries that has duplicate name
// [{name: Mary, age: 27}]

users.whereDistinct(key: (user) => user['name']); // entries that has distinct name
users.whereDistinct(key: (user) => user['age']); // entries that has distinct age

users.whereUnique(key: (user) => user['name']); // entries that has unique name
users.whereUnique(key: (user) => user['age']); // entries that has unique age

users.whereUnique(key: (user) => '${user['name']} ${user['age']}'); // unique rows
users.whereDuplicate(key: (user) => '${user['name']} ${user['age']}'); // duplicate rows
users.whereUnique(key: (user) => user['name'].toLowerCase()); // entries with unique name(case-insenstive)
```

If you want to select just the duplicate names:

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic>> users = [
  {"name": 'John', 'age': 18},
  {"name": 'Jane', 'age': 21},
  {"name": 'Mary', 'age': 23},
  {"name": 'Mary', 'age': 27},
  {"name": 'Ronn', 'age': 27},
];

// case-senstive
var users1 = users.whereDuplicate(key: (user) => user['name']);
// case-insenstive
var users2 = users.whereDuplicate(key: (user) => user['name'].toLowerCase());

print(users1); // [{name: Mary, age: 27}]
print(users1.map((user) => user['name'])); // [Mary]
```