# How to remove indentical ones from list dart :flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a list like this in my dart file:

```
List data = [{anjaaabq, 5:30}, {anjaaabq, 9:00}, {anjaaabq, 5:30},
{anjaaabq, 9:00},{amammama, 5:30}, {amammama, 9:00}, {anjaaabq, 5:30},
{anjaaabq, 9:00},{amammama, 5:30}, {amammama, 9:00}, {anjaaabq, 5:30},
{anjaaabq, 9:00},{amammama, 5:30}, {amammama, 9:00}, {arun, 5:30}, 
{arun, 9:00}];
```

So, I want to make this look like

```
[{anjaaabq, 5:30}, {anjaaabq, 9:00}, {amammama, 5:30}, {amammama, 9:00},
{arun, 5:30}, {arun, 9:00}];
```

How can I remove identical objects from this list?

i tried to `data = data.toString`
but it only showing
`{{anjaaabq, 5:30}, {anjaaabq, 5:30}, {anjaaabq, 5:30}, {anjaaabq, 5:30}}`
like this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete duplicates in a Dart List? list.distinct()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030613/how-can-i-delete-duplicates-in-a-dart-list-list-distinct)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toSet()` method, which will conver it into a set. A set is a list with unique elements. So just call this after your list:

```
List data = [{anjaaabq, 5:30}, {anjaaabq, 9:00}, {anjaaabq, 5:30},
{anjaaabq, 9:00},{amammama, 5:30}, {amammama, 9:00}, {anjaaabq, 5:30},
{anjaaabq, 9:00},{amammama, 5:30}, {amammama, 9:00}, {anjaaabq, 5:30},
{anjaaabq, 9:00},{amammama, 5:30}, {amammama, 9:00}, {arun, 5:30}, 
{arun, 9:00}];

List uniqueData = data.toSet().toList(); // will give you the list you want, with unique items.
```

Comment: use `List uniqueData = data.toSet().toList();` it'll work.

Comment: i also tried that too but that didnt worked

Comment: the list was the same , no change

Comment: What are your `amammama` objects? This means that they aren't identical.  Or flutter can't tell that they are identical, because you haven't set up equality operators for them. Post those classes.

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much all at last i got the solution

````
List arrayTrap =[];





void main(){
   
  data.forEach((element){
    
    arrayTrap.add(element.toString());
    
  });
  print(arrayTrap.toSet().toList());
  
}```

i just convert that into string before convert in to set


so i got output like:
```[{anjaaabq, 5:30}]```
````