# Remove duplicate dart

Tags: flutter, dart

there is a list:

```
@Koolkid3
@Peetea
@Peetea
@Ruptan
@bulunabu
@ptygma
@ptygma
```

Here's what to get:

```
@Koolkid3
@Ruptan
@bulunabu
```

If there are duplicates, then you need to remove them completely. Therefore, `toSet()` will not work here. How to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete duplicates in a Dart List? list.distinct()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030613/how-can-i-delete-duplicates-in-a-dart-list-list-distinct)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following:

```
  List<String> list = [
    "@Koolkid3",
    "@Peetea",
    "@Peetea",
    "@Ruptan",
    "@bulunabu",
    "@ptygma",
    "@ptygma"
  ];
  var occurrenceCount = Map();

  list.forEach((x) => occurrenceCount[x] = !occurrenceCount.containsKey(x) ? (1) : (occurrenceCount[x] + 1));

  list.retainWhere((element) => occurrenceCount[element] == 1);
  print(list);
```

Use a `Map` to count occurrence of each item, then use `retainWhere` to only keep the items that occur once.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert `List` to `Set` to remove duplicates. If needed again convert it into list.

```dart
 List<String> list = ["a", "v", "a"];

 print(list.toSet().toList()); //[a, v]
```

Removing duplicates and itself

```dart
List<String> list = ["a", "v", "a"];

list.removeWhere(
  (String s1) => list.where((s2) => s1 == s2).length > 1,
);

print(list); /// [v]
```

Comment: No, I need only v left in your case

Comment: You are left with 1 option. If there are duplicates, then you need to delete them completely, and you will have 1 option

Comment: This option looks nice syntactically, but it will have a time complexity of O(n2) since it will loop over the full list for each item in the list. My approach will perform better, but this one is simpler to understand :)

Comment: Well, I am not able to judge this, doing `forEach`, creating new map, finding with `containsKey` and again iterating map.; It describes the process But  I prefer shortcut without errors.